# Making histogram bins uniform - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, statistics, histogram

I've been working on a project related to image analysis in MATLAB. A part of it requires me to create multiple sets of histograms to compare the distribution of values for GCLM coefficients that I calculated for the images.

I'm using the PH2 database, with a total of 200 images (80, 80, 40 in three categories by diagnosis). I made histograms showing the distribution of every diagnosis and I also want to overlay the histograms to show how the distributions compare. This is the code I'm using:

```
    % DECOMP MAX
    figure
    for k=1:4
        subplot(2,2,1)
            h0 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 0,k),10);
            h0.FaceColor = 'green';
            title('Typical')
        subplot(2,2,2)
            h1 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 1,k),10);
            h1.FaceColor = 'yellow';
            title('Atypical')
        subplot(2,2,3)
            h2 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 2,k),10);
            h2.FaceColor = 'red';
            title('Melanoma')
        subplot(2,2,4)
            h0 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 0,k),10);
            hold on
            h1 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 1,k),10);
            h2 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 2,k),10);
            h0.FaceColor = 'green';
            h1.FaceColor = 'yellow';
            h2.FaceColor = 'red';
            title('Overlayed')
        suptitle(names_gclm{:,k})
        fname = sprintf('maxdecomp%d', k);
        set(gcf, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0 0 1 1]);
        saveas(gcf,fname,'png')
        close all
    end
```

My problem begins with the overlay part. Try as I might, I haven't been able to make the bins look uniform for all three diagnoses. I tried manually setting the bin numbers as well as the bar and bin width. Is there something I'm missing? What else could I try? I'd appreciate any suggestions as I'm at the end of my wits.

Here are two example images - as you see, the melanoma histogram ends up looking completely off next to the others in the first one. In the second one, every group looks different, making it impossible to compare distributions.
[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

Comment: When you say you want the bins to be uniform do you mean [histogram equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) or that you want the bins to have uniform spacing, i.e. each bin having the same width?

Comment: It may be easier if you could you post an example output image and describe what is wrong with it.

Comment: @jodag - I've edited the post with images. I hope my problem makes more sense now!

Comment: Have you tried specifying [bin edges](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html#inputarg_edges) rather than the number of bins in each histogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to explicitly [define the bin edges](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html#buhzt18-1). You are simply telling the histogram function that you want 10 bins. This results in uniform spacing from the minimum and maximum values of the data which is undesirable if the each dataset has different bounds. Instead, define the bin edges explicitly as follows...

```
% DECOMP MAX
figure
for k=1:4
    % determine bin edges
    edge_min = min(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 0 | diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 1 | diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 2,k))
    edge_max = max(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 0 | diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 1 | diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 2,k))
    edges = linspace(edge_min, edge_max, 10+1);

    subplot(2,2,1)
        h0 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 0,k),edges);
        h0.FaceColor = 'green';
        title('Typical')
    subplot(2,2,2)
        h1 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 1,k),edges);
        h1.FaceColor = 'yellow';
        title('Atypical')
    subplot(2,2,3)
        h2 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 2,k),edges);
        h2.FaceColor = 'red';
        title('Melanoma')
    subplot(2,2,4)
        h0 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 0,k),edges);
        hold on
        h1 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 1,k),edges);
        h2 = histogram(gclm_decomp_max_p(diagn.ClinicalDiagnosis == 2,k),edges);
        h0.FaceColor = 'green';
        h1.FaceColor = 'yellow';
        h2.FaceColor = 'red';
        title('Overlayed')
        % set plot limits to bin bounds
        xlim([edge_min edge_max]);
        ax = axis();
    % make sure all the axis have same limits
    subplot(2,2,1);
        axis(ax);
    subplot(2,2,2);
        axis(ax);
    subplot(2,2,3);
        axis(ax);

    suptitle(names_gclm{:,k})
    fname = sprintf('maxdecomp%d', k);
    set(gcf, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0 0 1 1]);
    saveas(gcf,fname,'png')
    close all
end
```

*Edit*: Updated with complete solution.

Comment: I know it's not exactly good etiquette to post comments like this, but I wanted to express the sheer amount of gratitude I feel - this has worked like a charm! Thank you so, so much.